# Executing a command randomly in ZSH

Tags: zsh

I would like to call a command mycommand randomly using ZSH. How can I achieve this?

Context: I have a command that I want to be executed every week on Mac OS. The simplest thing I have found is to add it in my .zshrc - bonus point I am sure to reinstall this upon full system reinstallation. But since it uses a pipenv virtualenv it's taking a few precious milliseconds when starting. I would be very happy if I could only spawn it with a 10% probability.

Comment: You don't want to run it *randomly*, you want to run it *periodically*. Use `cron`.

Comment: Why do you care about a few milliseconds for something that runs once a week? Note that you don't need to activate a virtual environment first; that's a convenience for working in the shell. If the virtual environment is in `/some/dir/venv`, you can simply run `/some/dir/venv/python myScript`.

Comment: Thanks for the comment about calling directly the interpreter much more efficient. As per the cron comment, as stated above it sucks on MacOS to setup something of the sort, and since it has only this specific usage I would be scared to not reinstall it upon reinstallation.

Comment: I'm not sure why you think setting up `cron` "sucks" on macOS. Create the job with `crontab -e`, and `launchd` takes care of running `cron` if it sees an appropriate configuration file anywhere.

Comment: Thanks for this comment, I will investigate this when I find a few minutes. Though an issue will remain of the computer being on at execution time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do a

```
((RANDOM % 10 == 1)) && mycommand
```

for making it 10% likely. Of course you also need to ensure then that it is executed not more than once per week, if it is important for you, but from your question, I assume that this is something you have already a solution for, and are interested only in introducing probability.

Comment: This is not really 10 % ;-). The random variable RANDOM generates a pseudo-random number between 0 and 32767. This implies that if you want to generate a random number between 0 and n, you cannot use the mod. The problem here is that the first 32768%n numbers will have a higher chance to be drawn.

Comment: Correct, because the largest possible value in RANDOM is not a power of 10, but the difference should not matter here. A more serious point could be that the seed is not entirely random. In my environment, I therefore explicitly seed the random generator by doing a `RANDOM=$(($(od -vAn -N2 -tu2 < /dev/urandom)))`. I'm not sure that this kind of accuracy is of importance to the OP.

Comment: Since zsh makes use of floating point arithmetic, I would suggest to use `(( 10 * RANDOM/32768. < 1 ))`

Comment: @kvantour : If we go that far, why multiplying by 10? Wouldn't `((RANDOM/32768. < 0.1))` be simpler?

Comment: Many thanks your answer! I will take a couple pills to relax thinking about the distribution not being perfectly linear ;-)